# Catching Ctrl + Z with Flex running in IE8

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts

For some reason I cannot catch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> `keyDown` event in my Flex application when it runs in IE. It works fine in FF/Chrome/Safari.

I have a simple `Group` control where I listen for `keyDown` and try implement my own Undo logic. I need to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> because any other key combination would feel unnatural to most users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently heard of some cases where `ctrlKey` would not work correctly on `keyDown`.  Try using `keyUp` instead.

Comment: Right you are. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The key combination is probably caught by the browser.
Unfortunately, when it comes to shortcuts, there are a lot of inconstancies between Flash and the different browsers.

I've already thought about that and one solution I could think of is using this [javascript library](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) and communicate key events to your flash app

Please note, most of inconstancies come from browsers themselves and not the Flash VM :
[link text](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)